# Anticipated Graduation Date on Background Check

Tags: resume, background-check

I recently accepted a job offer for a great job.  My online application shows my employment and education history. For my current masters I had written down the anticipated graduation date as December 2019 and then indicated “no” when it asked if I had graduated.  I will be done in spring 2020.  The degree is not required for the job, though they were happy to see I was pursuing it.

As part of the standard due diligence the company is conducting a background check that will also verify my employment and education history.  The background screening company sent me a form asking for me to fill out some personal information and reconfirm my employment and education history which was pre-populated from the online application.  I cannot remember and can’t revisit the background screening  form to confirm if It had the anticipated graduation date marked down correctly.  I am now concerned that it may show as me graduating in 2019 and they would use this as grounds to rescind the offer.  It is fairly easy to confirm with the university that  I am enrolled and slated to be complete by spring 2020.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think this will matter. I don't think this was a deliberate lie as you either typed in the wrong thing or are now expecting to graduate later. You said that it's not required for the job so I wouldn't worry about it. If they ask, then just tell them what happened. They're not going to rescind your offer all because you were off by one semester in your anticipated graduation.

Comment: On a complete side note, before I got my job, I went to graduate school for a semester before getting accepted to my current job. The form asked me for an expected graduation date and I just put a few semesters later. I decided now that this graduate school program isn't how I wanted to pursue and enhance my career so now I'm out of my graduate studies for now and I'll be pursuing in something else later on.

Comment: Make sure that the data you supply now is correct to the best of your knowledge. If earlier data wasn't fully correct, so be it. They'll either understand or they won't, but that's not under your control.

Comment: Why did you put December 2019 in the first place? Has the anticipated date changed?

Answer (score 1):

It probably shouldn't be an issue, that's why it's "anticipated" graduation date, because things can change.  That said, I would probably email your company internal contact (probably someone in HR) to let them know the mixup.  Just say something like "I may have filled in this form wrong, here's the correct info" or something like that.  This isn't something you can realistically hide from them anyway; if they request a start date of Jan 1 or something and you're like "sure but I can only work part time because of...reasons", that's way sketchier than being straightforward with them now.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Just to clarify it’s a graduate degree I am earning part time in the evenings while I work as a full-time employee. The graduation date would not impact my start date in any way.  My main concern was if it made me seem like a liar.

Comment: You seem way more like a liar if you don't disclose it to them now and then they find out later by some other means.